# a single word for "take interest in"

Tags: single-word-requests

> An effective metaphor will help your readers understand, remember, and ___________ your idea.

I have been looking for a single word to fill in that blank that means "take interest in." Why? Perhaps because a single word will feel nicely parallel.

[Thesaurus.com](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/take%20interest%20in?s=t) gives me synonyms for the sense of "enjoy" or "be fond of," such as *admire, approve, cherish, love, fancy, relish, dig,* etc. But the meaning I'm looking for is not really "enjoy" or "be fond of."

Synonyms for "interest," as in "attraction" or "curiosity" include *concern, enthusiasm*, and *passion*. But the verb forms of those nouns certainly don't work in my sentence, with "your idea" as the object. Nor do the verbs *fascinate* or *involve*.

Isolating the "interest" idea and using the verb form, I might say "An effective metaphor will interest your reader," but that means the metaphor itself is interesting to the reader, not the idea that it illustrates.

So... is there a single word for "take interest in"?

Comment: _appreciate_ comes to mind, but I don't think it's quite right, either.

Comment: *engage*, perhaps, although *engage with* would probably be clearer.

Comment: Ideas *interest* people, *amuse* people, *attract* people, *intrigue* people, *entertain* people... but what do **people** do *to* or *with* ideas? I would fill the blank in with *apply*, but that is not exactly *take interest in*. It is more like the ultimate goal of ideas.

Comment: They take interest in them

Comment: **attend to** or one of the synonyms of *attend* might set you on the right track.

Comment: The subtleties of *interest* combined with the dearth of transitive verbs relating to ideas make this a particularly interesting challenge.

Comment: @ScotM: yes... the answers below intersect with "interest" on some level (and I agree with the voters that "appreciate" comes closest) but none perfectly convey "take interest in." Perhaps "taking interest in" is something that is not inspired, but comes from within. In my sentence the metaphor operates as an agent, facilitating something. And I wonder if the word "help"  is somehow running interference. That is, we "help" as in "assist" someone to understand or remember, but do we assist someone to take interest in something? Perhaps that part just needs its own expression...

Comment: There might be some value in refining your sense of which subtlety in *take interest* you are actually looking for. The etymology of the phrase might help, but I have no tool to search the etymology of that phrase. If you are actually looking for "take interest in" that may end up as your best choice.

Comment: @ScotM: The sense I'm looking for is that of curiosity. The idea that an effective metaphor will make a reader feel "oh, that's interesting, I want to keep reading." That seems different than "appreciating."

Answer (score 5):

Try [**appreciate:**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/appreciate)

> VERB
>
> [WITH OBJECT]
>
> 1 Recognize the full worth of:
>
> *she feels that he does not **appreciate** her*

(Definition and example from Oxforddictionaries.com)

Comment: ***Interest*** and ***appreciate*** seem to intersect in the notion of **value**. *Appreciate* implies *value* from the Latin *pretium*: http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=appraise&allowed_in_frame=0 *interest* seems to derive the meaning of *value* from the intuitive sense of *intersection of essence* producing mutual benefit: http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=interest&allowed_in_frame=0.

Answer (score 1):

There are two suggestions in this answer, ***embrace***, and ***pursue***.

---

> An effective metaphor will help your readers understand, remember, and ***embrace*** your idea.

This suggests that your readers are helped to readily accept the idea.

> : to hold someone in your arms as a way of expressing love or friendship 
>   : to accept (something or someone) readily or gladly
>   : to use (an opportunity) eagerly
>   <sub>[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/embrace)</sub>

---

> An effective metaphor will help your readers understand, remember, and ***pursue*** your idea.

This suggests that your readers are helped to follow the idea further.

> : to follow and try to catch or capture (someone or something) for usually a long distance or time
>   : to try to get or do (something) over a period of time
>   : to be involved in (an activity)
>   <sub>[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pursue)</sub>

Comment: I think this is the best answer so far.

Answer (score 1):

[**Merriam-Webster Dictionary *online***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ponder)

> **pon•der** *verb* \ˈpän-dər\ : to think about or consider (something) carefully
>
> **Full Definition of PONDER** transitive verb
>
> **1**: to weigh in the mind: appraise (*pondered* their chances of success)
>
> **2**:  to think about: reflect on (*pondered* the events of the day) 
>   intransitive verb: to think or consider especially quietly, soberly, and deeply 
>   — *pon•der•er* noun
>
> **Origin of PONDER**
>
> Middle English, from Middle French *ponderer*, from Latin *ponderare* to weigh, ponder, from *ponder*-, *pondus* weight — more at PENDANT
>
> **First Known Use**: 14th century
>
> **Related to PONDER**
>
> *Synonyms* chew over, cogitate, consider, **contemplate**, debate, deliberate, entertain, eye, kick around, **meditate**, mull (over), perpend, pore (over), question, revolve, ruminate, study, think (about or over), turn, weigh, wrestle (with), beat one's brains out (about), chew on, cudgel one's brains (about), look at

Additionally, you might consider...

> **CONTEMPLATE** *transitive verb*:
>
> **1**) to view or consider with continued attention :  meditate on (*contemplate* the vastness of the universe)
>
> **2**): to view as contingent or probable or as an end or intention (*contemplate* marriage)
>
> *intransitive verb*: ponder, meditate
>
> [**Merriam-Webster Dictionary *online***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/contemplate?show=0&t=1422047852)
>
> **Ponder** *vs*. **Contemplate**: an [**Ngram query**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ponder%2C+contemplate&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cponder%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccontemplate%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: While I was pondering this post on my bed last night, the word *ponder* seemed like an appropriate option. The implication of *appraise* in its definition, and the historical association between weight and value, connect *ponder* to *appreciate* and *interest* in a subtle kind of way.

Comment: I agree, @ScotM, *ponder* carries the additional connotation of *contemplation*, plus it's used less frequently though still not obscure.

Answer (score 1):

Some thoughts -

*Grasp.  Accept.  Adopt.  Espouse.  Seize.  Support.*

With a connotation of theft -

*Appropriate.  Borrow.  Steal.*

I think the best, as mentioned in another response, is *embrace*.

Answer (score 0):

How about "consider" - as in: "think about"?

Answer (score 0):

Absorb, assimilate, share

Absorb:
* verb:  engage or engross wholly ("Her interest in butterflies absorbs her completely")
* verb:  take up mentally ("He absorbed the knowledge or beliefs of his tribe")

Assimilate:
* verb:  become similar to one's environment ("Immigrants often want to assimilate quickly")
* verb:  make similar ("This country assimilates immigrants very quickly")
* verb:  take (gas, light or heat) into a solution
* verb:  take up mentally

Answer (score 0):

After reading the elaboration of what you're after in your discussion with ScotM, it seems to me that **engage with** is the term that best fits your requirement:

> An effective metaphor will help your readers understand, remember, and **engage with** your idea.

This option meets your stipulation that

> "The sense I'm looking for is that of curiosity. The idea that an effective metaphor will make a reader feel "oh, that's interesting, I want to keep reading"."

The only minus point is that it is two words, not the single word you were hoping for. But otherwise, I think it's an excellent fit.